# ROS Indigo :Cannot show Graph View on smach_viewer

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.

My development environment is Ubuntu14.04 and ROS Indigo.

I tried to execute ROS service as a smach state and it works correctly.

But, when I run smach_viewer, the following errors occured and print nothing.
(I think smach_viewer can print this graph in Ubuntu12.04 + ROS Hydro :'()

---

### error message

```
Exception in thread Thread-6:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/smach_viewer/smach_viewer.py", line 848, in _update_graph
    self.set_dotcode(dotstr,zoom=False)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/smach_viewer/smach_viewer.py", line 866, in set_dotcode
    if self.widget.set_dotcode(dotcode, None):
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xdot/wxxdot.py", line 455, in set_dotcode
    self.set_xdotcode(xdotcode)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xdot/wxxdot.py", line 483, in set_xdotcode
    self.graph = parser.parse()
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xdot/xdot.py", line 1146, in parse
    DotParser.parse(self)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xdot/xdot.py", line 951, in parse
    self.parse_graph()
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xdot/xdot.py", line 960, in parse_graph
    self.parse_stmt()
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xdot/xdot.py", line 993, in parse_stmt
    self.parse_subgraph()
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xdot/xdot.py", line 974, in parse_subgraph
    self.parse_stmt()
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xdot/xdot.py", line 993, in parse_stmt
    self.parse_subgraph()
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xdot/xdot.py", line 974, in parse_subgraph
    self.parse_stmt()
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xdot/xdot.py", line 1009, in parse_stmt
    self.handle_node(id, attrs)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xdot/xdot.py", line 1120, in handle_node
    shapes.extend(parser.parse())
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xdot/xdot.py", line 608, in parse
    points = self.read_polygon()
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xdot/xdot.py", line 503, in read_polygon
    x, y = self.read_point()
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xdot/xdot.py", line 486, in read_point
    x = self.read_number()
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xdot/xdot.py", line 480, in read_number
    return int(self.read_code())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '274.67'
```

---

- When I run the command below,
  $ rostopic echo /server_name/smach/container_status
  I receive msg like this.

header:
seq: 5
stamp:
secs: 1401776891
nsecs: 761457920
frame_id: ''
path: /SM_ROOT
initial_states: ['SPAWN']
active_states: ['None']
local_data: � }q.
info: HEARTBEAT

Many thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/172688/ros-indigo-:cannot-show-graph-view-on-smach_viewer/) by [hashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/18772/hashi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 226 on 2014-06-03

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andreas T.](https://answers.ros.org/users/19196/andreas-t./) on 2014-06-30**:
Hey have you solve this problem? I have the same on Ubuntu 14.04. with Indigo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Even though I still get an "TypeError: String or Unicode type required",a graph appeared on Smart a Viewer

when I rewrote the 480th row of the /opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xdot/xdot.py

> `return int(self.read_code()) -> return int(float(self.read_code()))`

---

Originally posted by [hashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/18772/hashi/) with karma: 226 on 2014-06-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 14

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andreas T.](https://answers.ros.org/users/19196/andreas-t./) on 2014-07-07**:
Thanks it works.

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2014-07-31**:
thanks, is this a valid bug in smach?

**Comment by [hashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/18772/hashi/) on 2014-08-03**:
Sorry, I'm not sure yet.

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2014-08-05**:
I confirm this solves the problem for me using Indigo under Ubuntu 14.04

**Comment by [noe.eon](https://answers.ros.org/users/20225/noe.eon/) on 2014-09-18**:
This fixed the problem, but unmasked another. I now consistently get "segmentation faults" when attempting to run the smach_viewer. Anybody run into this problem? Or suggest where I should post this question?

ROS: Indigo
OS: Ubuntu 14.04
python-wx: 2.8

**Comment by [Wedontplay](https://answers.ros.org/users/18883/wedontplay/) on 2014-11-06**:
I got sporadic segfault errors too but I had it also before when the states weren't visualized.
@hashi I signaled your solution here: [link text](https://github.com/jbohren/xdot/issues/5)